# RStudio Cloud. install packages failed

Tags: r, rstudio

I've got error trying to download the library in RStudio Cloud.

```
install.packages('tidyverse')
```

It installed but...

```
library(tidyverse)
Error: package or namespace load failed for 
‘tidyverse’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], 
c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘haven’
```

I tried to google it. Manually installation of the package 'haven' doesn't help.

```
install.packages('tidyverse',dependencies = TRUE)
```

This also does not work.

Any ideas how can I fix the problem?

Earlier I installed this package many times and everything was fine. The problem appeared yesterday. Are there any malfunctions in RStudio Cloud?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the result of `getOption("repos")` in your culprit instance?
It seems to me that `haven` is just in the process of being updated to 2.0.0 atm, since windows binaries are 1.1.2 but source version is 2.0.0 - maybe that's related to your problem.

Comment: @AlexR Thanks for your comment
`getOption("repos")`

                     `CRAN                      RSPM `

  `"http://package-proxy"` `"http://cran.rstudio.org" `
So, what should I do? Just wait for finisising the updating proccess?

Comment: cran.studio.com has haven. Can you try a manual install.packages(„haven“)?